# Sum of real answers to $\frac{x^2+4x+1}{x}+\frac{3x}{x^2+4x+1}=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2+4x+1}{x}+\frac{3x}{x^2+4x+1}=4
\end{equation}

I need the sum of real answers.. Can anyone help?

Comment: So you have $y+\frac 3y=4$... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Simplify and use vieta's rule

Comment: @Sky Viète's formula gives the sum of all roots, including the complex ones.

Comment: @egreg Apologies, I did not notice they only wanted real roots.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: multiplying with $x(x^2+4x+1)$ and factorizing the degree $4$ polynomial gives
$$
(x^2 + 3x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking $y={x^2+4x+1\over x}$, the original equation becomes $y+\frac 3y=4$.  By inspection, the roots in $y$ are at $y=1,3$, therefore we get ${x^2+4x+1\over x}=1,3$ which becomes $x^2+3x+1=0,\,x^2+x+1=0$.  Only the form $x^2+3x+1=0$ has real solutions, and by Viète these have sum $-3$.

Comment: Why are the formulas by  François Viète called [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) in english and german ?

Comment: I blame Latin for this.